# How do you install Boost.Build on Windows?

Tags: c++, boost, build, installation

http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html

Tried following those instructions, but they do not work.

What I did:

Open cmd.exe;
cd C:\BoostBuild\boost-build
.\bootstrap.bat

What I get:

C:\BoostBuild\boost-build>.\bootstrap.bat
'.\bootstrap.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you download and unzip a copy of boost in `C:\`, you should end up with a folder like `C:\boost_1_48_0`

In this folder, execute bootstrap.bat; so

```
cd C:\boost_1_48_0
bootstrap
```

Comment: Do this require you to have a visual studio shell (the one that puts `cl`, `link`, etc. in your `PATH` environment variable)?

Comment: It does need to be able to find `cl` and `link`, but I think a default VS install sets the path to `Common7\Tools` in an env var like `VS100COMNTOOLS` which I think is all bootstrap needs to run successfully.

Comment: I did this from the visual studio command prompt on windows and it worked. I'm using boost 1.52.0 and have VS 2010 Professional (not express, but I think express should work the same way).

Answer (score 1):

You  do not need the .\ portion, that's a unix reference that refers to a file in the same folder.

```
launch CMD.exe
CD C:\BoostBuild\boost-build  <press-enter>
bootstrap <press-enter>
```

is the right way to do this from DOS/CMD.

Edit referring to the comment:

What you're doing is chaining the commands accidentally, try this:

```
<Run> CMD <press enter.
<type> CD c:\boostbuild\boost-build <press enter>
<type> bootstrap <press enter>
```

If that worked correctly then after typing the 2nd line above. the prompt C:\Users\Furiosity\ should have changed to C:\BoostBuild\bood-build

Comment: C:\Users\Furiosity>CD C:\BoostBuild\boost-build
C:\BoostBuild\boost-build>bootstrap
'bootstrap' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Is what I got

Don't know how to wrap quotes. Sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

cl.exe -- compiler embedded within visual C++ or visual studio. used Visual C++ express free edition and its command prompt bootstrap or other command of b2 works fine.

This sets the boost.build installed.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that after I unzipped the boost, the window defender removed the bootstrap.bat from the "c:\boost\" directory. And for that reason I was looking all over the internet to find out why that file doesn't exist or how this file might be created. I excluded the path from windows defender's searching path, there it was. To run it you have to have admin access (at least in my case).