# error C2182: '*' : illegal use of type 'void' c:\boost_1_53_0\boost\smart_ptr\intrusive_ptr.hpp

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, build-error, websocket++

I'm trying to develop a websocket++ server on my windows 7 laptop for ease (not good with `vi` yet, don't want to constantly ftp).  I will move to Ubuntu 12.10 at the end.

I'm using a Visual C++ Win32 Console Application project.

I've `include`d the `websocketpp` directory, installed boost 1.53.0 [How do you install Boost.Build on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388488/how-do-you-install-boost-build-on-windows), and `include`d & `link`ed boost [Boost linking, Visual Studio & version control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335040/boost-linking-visual-studio-version-control).

I'm trying to `build` `print_server.cpp` http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/building-program-websocket

When I do, I get `Error 1   error C2182: '*' : illegal use of type 'void'   c:\boost_1_53_0\boost\smart_ptr\intrusive_ptr.hpp   Line:155    Column:1`

The boost code is (second line is 155):

```
T & operator*() const
{
    BOOST_ASSERT( px != 0 );
    return *px;
}
```

Why am I getting this error?  How do I fix it?

Comment: The actual error is _not_ in the Boost header, it's how you use Boost. Somewhere you use the dereference operator on a Boost smart pointer which has the type `void`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue when compiling using boost on VCPP. WebSocket++ 0.3 does not use intrusive_ptr, but it does use static_pointer_cast. Each boost smart pointer implements their own overload of boost::static_pointer_cast. VCPP appears to be unable to choose the correct overload when static casting a `shared_ptr<void>` to a `shared_ptr<connection_ptr>`. Clang and GCC both use the correct overload, VCPP doesn't. I have a little demo program that demonstrates this issue that I've been meaning to clean up and ask Stack Overflow about...

A simple fix in the meantime is to tell WebSocket++ to use C++11  rather than boost smart pointers. VCPP works correctly with std::static_pointer_cast / std::shared_ptr. Per http://www.zaphoyd.com/websocketpp/manual/reference/cpp11-support defining `_WEBSOCKETPP_CPP11_MEMORY_` before including WebSocket++ headers will accomplish this. I've tested VCPP2010's implementation of C++11 `<memory>` and it implements everything that WebSocket++ needs.